# EOFException DataInputStream using readUTF

Tags: java, datainputstream, eofexception

I ve coded a simple Server that Listen for client and when the client is connected it opens a Datainputstream that read all the data sent from client( my client wirte UTF data).

This is the ServerCode:

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    try {           
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7000);
        while(true){
        System.out.println("Il Server sta cercando Connessioni");
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Il Server ha accettato un Client");

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){             
                   try {
                    while(true){
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    isAlreadyOpened = true;                     
                    System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    isAlreadyOpened = false;
                }  
            }           
        });
        if(!isAlreadyOpened){
        t2.start();
        }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is very basic and My client is an Andorid App that send data when button is clicked:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("Testiamo sto socket");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Everything is perfect when the client is connected to the server. But when I click just one time the Client's button, the data sent is displayed in my server logs but immediatly after the exception is thrown.

```
Il Server sta cercando Connessioni
Il Server ha accettato un Client
Il Server sta cercando Connessioni
Testiamo sto socket
java.io.EOFException
   at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
   at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
   at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
```

reading from Oracle documentation this exception is thrown <>. 
But how can I avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried to put an if statement before readuTF like `if(dis.readUTF() != null){do the stuff}`

Comment: Yes I have tried it. But it doesn't work.. it throws the exception But it doesn't print neither once the data. So I think it is worse than before..

Comment: `while(true)...` statements are not efficient and should be avoided. `EOFException` is End Of File Exception. So that means that you are doing something wrong (maybe reading stuff that doesn't exist).

Comment: While(true) is set to allow server to listen for data forever. I don't think there is an alternative way to do so..
The problem is that when client sends the data the server can read it.. But since it is inside a while loop.. at the second time there is no data to read so it throws exception. And this is what I would like to avoid even if I need the server that listen everytime for data.

Comment: @xdevs23 Your statement about `while (true)` statements not being efficient is 100% nonsense. Nothing could be more efficient.

Comment: @Briesanji That method doesn't return null. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are sending one string and then closing the connection. You are trying to read infinitely many strings. They aren't being sent. What you're getting instead is the *expected* `EOFException.`

There is no problem here to solve. If you need to send more strings over the same connection, don't close it after sending one.

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer.. i didn't get it. I thought the connection wasn't closed beacause Server side everything is good.. The problem was the client that after flushing the outputstream closed the socket. I simply deleted dos.close() and everything worked.. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Although this was not Alesso's problem, here's another way that the EOFException can occur:

You open an output stream to a file and then later open an input stream to that same file without closing the output stream first.